# Angular templates: prevent Pseudo elements from wrapping

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using a :after to add a popup icon at the end of my text in an Angular App. How do you prevent the icon from wrapping on its own? I want to attach it to the last word. But in my use case the text is Angular data within {{Text}}

If this wasn't an angular application I would normally do something like:

```
<p>This is my <span class="popUp">sentence</span></p>
```

CSS

```
.popUp:after {
     content: "\e62a"
}
```

But my usecase is

```
<p>{{Text}}<span class="popUp"></span></p>
```

Comment: If there is no space between `{{Text}}` and the popUp span, then the last word will stay together with the span (which sounds like what you want). Can you describe better what the problem is?

Comment: That's the thing, there is no space between the {{Text}} and the popUp span. This is what is confusing me. The Text variable in my component is this.Text = "This is a sentence".

The problem is when I go into responsive mode and decrease my browser width the popUp icon is wrapping to the next line on its own. I want the icon attached to the word sentence so if it needs to wrap both the word "sentence" and the popUp go to the next line

Comment: That's exactly how it should already be working. Can you share your CSS? (Instead of "some CSS")

Comment: I updated the css code in the question. I'm just bringing the icon in with a unicode content.

Comment: Can you please reproduce your issue in stackblitz?

Comment: Proving to be a little difficult, but I'm trying to mock something up